# Windows 10 - Cannot remove one display language

Tags: windows-10, language, language-pack

A friend's Laptop came with windows 10 but, for some reason, had Polish language installed by default.

I added the English and Greek language (these are the ones he needed) and setup English as default. I logged out and back in. The problem is that, every know and then, it reverts to Polish, so I need to remove it. Here are the details:

1. Settings -> Time & Language -> Language:

   - It shows English as windows display language but there is also Greek and Polski in the drop down menu
   - In the preferred languages, Polski is not shown so there is no way to remove it. I actually added polski (using "add a preferred language") and removed it but still it remained as one of the 3 windows display languages.
2. `lpksetup /u` shows the GUI shown here:
   [image: Although Polish is not the display language, it shows it as system language]

Although Polish is not the display language, it shows it as system language

3. Using `Get-WinUserLanguageList` in the powershell shows only English and Greek

So, I think I exhausted any methods I could think of (apart from reinstalling). Is there a possible solution?

Comment: If you create a new user on the machine does the behavior change?  What is the default display language for that new user?

Comment: the new user has polish as default. It is baked in, somehow, in the installation.

Comment: If the new user had the incorrect language has default then you have not changed it.  This question was improperly closed as a duplicate, specifically, the incorrect duplicate (I believe I submitted an answer to a question in the past).  *I know exactly how to solve your problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have exhausted your possibilities. If the dealer used a customized install medium with a polish package you have no other option as setting a new system language (but without reinstalling completely) - Follow ALL the steps as described
**How to change default system language on Windows 10**

If you're using your device with the wrong language configuration, you don't need to reinstall Windows 10. You only need to change a few settings to set the correct system language.
Disabling language sync

When you use a Microsoft account on Windows 10, the language settings will sync across devices. In the case that you're planning to change the region and language settings for only one computer, you should disable the option to sync these settings before making any changes to prevent the new configuration from overwriting the settings on your other devices.

To disable language syncing on Windows 10, use these steps:

- Open Settings.
- Click on Accounts.
- Click on Sync your settings.
- Under the "Individual sync settings" section, turn off the "Language preferences" toggle switch.
  Once you complete the steps, you can change the language settings without affecting the settings on other devices.
  Changing system language

To change the system language on Windows 10, close any running app, and then use these steps:

- Open Settings.
- Click on Time & Language.
- Click on Language.
- Under the "Preferred languages" section, click the Add a preferred language button.<
- Search for the language you want on Windows 10.
- Select the language package from the result.
- Click the Next button.
- Check the Set as my display language option.
- Check the Install language pack option.
- Check or clear the additional language features as needed.
- Click the Install button
- Click the Yes, sign out now button.
- Sign back into the Windows 10 account.

After you complete the steps, the language will change across the entire Windows 10 experience. The new changes will be reflected in the Sign-in screen, Settings app, File Explorer, Desktop, apps, browser, and websites you visit. Also, depending on your new settings, Windows 10 may prompt you to review your privacy settings again.
Changing region settings

If you're changing the system language because you're located in a different region, you'll also need to update the region settings.

To change the local region settings on Windows 10, use these steps:

- Open Settings.
- Click on Time & Language.
- Click on Region.
- Use the "Country or region" drop-down menu to select your geographical location if different from your current settings.
- Under the "Regional format" section, use the drop-down menu to select the correct formats for dates and times if different from your region.
- Click on Language on the left pane.
- Under the "Related settings" section, in the right pane, click the Administrative language settings option.
- In the "Administrative" tab, click the Copy settings button.
- Under the "Copy your current settings to" section, check the Welcome screen and system accounts and New user accounts options.
- Click the OK button.
- Click the OK button again.
- Click the Restart now button.

Once you complete the steps, the device will display the correct region settings according to your physical location.
Remember that when changing the language settings, you may lose the ability to use Cortana, as the digital assistant is not supported in most regions. This should work toget rid of the polish language pack.

Comment: The user is not logged in with a Microsoft account. I have already done the other things mentioned, apart from some aspects of the regional settings. I will try them and report back.

Comment: As I said do it step by step - it works 100% even if you think you have done it already! Of course you can skip step 1 if noaccount is defined!

Comment: This regretfully doesn't work for me.
I have this for Brittish English, but regardless if I try to make Swedish or English US as default, it seems to work until I run lpksetup again - "English" (the UK one) is always the one with the warning-triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I just had something similar happening. I regularly switch between English and Arabic throughout the day but Hebrew was listed as an input language too, requiring an extra press of ALT+SHIFT to alternate between the 2 languages I use most frequently. However, Hebrew wasn't listed under Preferred Languages so I couldn't remove it! I searched online and couldn't find a solution so I decided to try installing Hebrew and immediately uninstalling it. And it worked!!

So... if there's an input language you can't remove, install it again and remove it. That might work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction on how to remove 'unremovable' language pack can be found in this answer:
https://superuser.com/a/1662219

It helped me.
You can find out what language packs are installed doing this:

1. Run CMD (Win+R -> `cmd`-> Enter);
2. Type `dism /Online /Get-Packages | findstr /c:"LanguagePack"`.

Output list can differ from what you see in Settings -> Time & Language -> Language.